# When submitting a spark streaming recevier, how to specify host without "failing through"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

I want to create a server socket to listen on, on a host that I know the ip and hostname ahead of time (and it shows up with that hostname in the yarn node list) . But I can't seem to get it to listen on that host without letting it fail an arbitrary number of times before hand.

There's a [Flume receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html) that has the sort of host-specific functionality I'm looking for.

```
FlumeUtils.createStream(streamingContext, [chosen machine's hostname], [chosen port])
```

My receiver code:

```
class TCPServerReceiver(hostname: String, port: Int)
  extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) with Logging {

  def onStart() {
    // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
    new Thread("Socket Receiver") {
      override def run() { receive() }
    }.start()
  }

  def onStop() {
  }

    private def receive() {
        /*  This is where the job fails until it happens to start on the correct host */
        val server = new ServerSocket(port, 50, InetAddress.getByName(hostname))

        var userInput: String = null
        while (true) {
            try {
                val s = server.accept()
                val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()))

                userInput  = in.readLine()
                while (!isStopped && userInput != null) {
                    store(userInput)
                    userInput = in.readLine()
                }
            } catch {
                case e: java.net.ConnectException =>
                    restart("Error connecting to " + port, e)
                case t: Throwable =>
                    restart("Error receiving data", t)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then to test it while it's running:

```
echo 'this is a test' | nc <hostname> <port>
```

This all works when I run as a local client, but when it's submitted to a yarn cluster, the logs show it trying to run in other containers on different hosts and all of them fail because the hostname doesn't match that of the container:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
```

**Eventually** (after several minutes), it does create the socket once the receiver tries to start on the correct host, so the above code *does* work, but it takes a substantial amount of "boot time" and I'm worried that adding more nodes will cause it to take even longer!

Is there a way of ensuring that this receiver starts on the correct host on the first try?

Comment: Is it required for your streaming process to start a TCP server on that specific host? An approach where the receiver discovers the host would not work?

Comment: btw, starting a server connection in Spark Streaming is kind of odd as the receivers are clients by nature, but should be possible as well.

Comment: I'm looking for a functionality similar to what is in the [Flume receiver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html) (also linked in the question). Starting a server connection may be odd, but there is certainly a precedence for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom `TCPServerReceiver` implementation should also implement:

```
def preferredLocation: Option[String]
```

> Override this to specify a preferred location (hostname).

In this case, something like:

```
def preferredLocation = Some(hostname)
```